# how to fix Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0

Tags: php

Why Undefined offset: 0 in line 4 in my code. Someone please help.

Below is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$sesiData = !empty($_SESSION['sesiData'])?$_SESSION['sesiData']:'';
if(!empty($sesiData['status']['msg'])){
$statusPsn = $sesiData['status']['msg'];
$jenisStatusPsn = $sesiData['status']['type'];
unset($_SESSION['sesiData']['status']);
}
?>
```